# Use more decimals in Python

Tags: python, decimal

I already have a code which uses the bisection method to determine the value of something, the problem is that I need a value so precise, more than 15 decimals, and at some point python stops getting smaller digits

I am aware of the Decimals library but do I really have to rewrite every parameter in the code as Decimals(parameter) ? because I have lots of parameters

is there a way to convert every float in the code to Decimals universally? or is there a way to solve this problem all together using a different way ?

```
62.5
31.25
15.625
23.4375
27.34375
25.390625
26.3671875
25.87890625
25.634765625
25.7568359375
25.81787109375
25.787353515625
25.7720947265625
25.76446533203125
25.760650634765625
25.758743286132812
25.75969696044922
25.759220123291016
25.758981704711914
25.758862495422363
25.758802890777588
25.758832693099976
25.75881779193878
25.75882524251938
25.75882151722908
25.75882337987423
25.758824311196804
25.75882477685809
25.758825009688735
25.758825126104057
25.758825184311718
25.758825155207887
25.758825140655972
25.758825133380014
25.758825137017993
25.758825138836983
25.758825139746477
25.758825140201225
25.75882513997385
25.758825139860164
25.75882513980332
25.7588251397749
25.75882513978911
25.758825139796215
25.758825139792663
25.758825139790886
25.758825139791774
25.75882513979222
25.758825139792442
25.75882513979233
25.758825139792386
25.758825139792414
25.7588251397924
25.758825139792407
25.758825139792403
25.758825139792407
25.758825139792407
25.758825139792407
25.758825139792407
25.758825139792407
25.758825139792407
25.758825139792407
```

You see at some point Python stops changing the value because it doesnt compute smaller digits

thank you

Comment: Please show an example of what you mean this has my interest but I need more to go off.

Comment: That doesn’t help, I was referring to adding code examples of what you want to change.

Comment: How much code do you have to refactor?  Wouldn't it be easier to modify than to try to recast the float type to decimal (which might have its own unintended consequences)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please show us some example code that shows your problem. Read and follow [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 3):

For `float` instances, Python uses machine-level double precision floating point numbers (`double` in C terms). What exactly this is depends on the platform and compiler that built Python.
These days it is most probably a [64-bit double-precision binary floating-point number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format). The 53-bit significand gives between 15 to 17 significant decimal digits.

If you use `numpy`, you can use the `long double` floating point number. This has a 64-bit sigificand, yielding  [approximately 18 decimal digits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_precision#Working_range).

`Decimal` values have *adjustable precision*. By default it is 28 significant digits, but you can change that. So changing to Decimal is probably a good choice *if you can get by with the standard mathematical operators and the limited amount of mathematical functions that `Decimal` supports*. But this would indeed mean changing all your code. It is part of the standard library, that might be a plus.

Alternatively, you could look at the [`mpmath`](http://mpmath.org/) library. This also allows you to set an arbitrary precision (it defaults to 15 significant digits). It supports much more advanced mathematics than `Decimal`. It implements all the functions from `math` and `cmath` and more. But here you would also have to convert your whole program to change `float` to the `mpf` type. By default, mpmath works with integers internally. When available, mpmath uses the Python bindings to the [gmp](https://pypi.org/project/gmpy/) library which makes it much faster, especially at high precision (>100 digits).

### Conclusion

If you want more precision, you will have to convert your program to use a arbitrary precision math module. Depending on how many `math` functions you use, `mpmath` looks like a better fit; it supports all functions from `math` and `cmath` and then some.

### How to convert

A total automatic conversion from `float` to `mpf` (or `Decimal`) types is not possible. But you can get most of the way there.

Both `Decimal` and `mpf` support the standard math operators. So you should not have to change those. You do need to look at places where you *create* or *input* floating point numbers and at places where you use functions from `math`.

First, change all instances of `float(` to `Decimal(` or `mpf(`. That takes care of explicitly created numbers.
Second, search for all floating point literals and replace them the same way. You can use your editor's search-and-replace function for this, or you can write a small Python script for it. So this can largely be automated.

Then look at all the functions that read data from a source (e.g. a file or database), and update them. This will probably have to be done manually, unless there these explicitly use `float()`, in which case they are handled by the abovementioned method.

If you are currently using the `math` module, you will have to search and replace those functions by their equivalents in the chosen module. In this case the search part can be easily automated.
If you have used `import math`, you can easily search for "`math.`" to find the functions that need replacing. In this case when using `mpmath`, you could simply replace "`math.`" with "`mpmath.`", since `mpmath` implements all functions from `math`.
If you have used `from math import x, y, z`, you need to search for x, y and z separately. You could even write a script to translate `math` functions to their equivalents in `Decimal` or `mpf`. It depends on the size and complexity of your code base if this is worth doing.

Answer (score 1):

You are asking if you can change the Python builtin type of floating point literals from `float` to (for example) `decimal.Decimal`. You can't do that.

**Other things to consider**

If `decimal.Decimal` is central to your code, you could import it with a shorter name:

```
from decimal import Decimal as Dec
x1 = Dec('0.234')
y1 = Dec('4.32')
x2 = Dec('4.321')
y2 = Dec('5.87')
```

Type annotations can help you to not miss conversions:

```
def distance(x1: Dec, y1: Dec, x2: Dec, y2: Dec) -> Dec:
    return Dec.sqrt((x2 - x1)**2 + (y2 - y1)**2)
```

If precision is important, initialize `decimal.Decimal` with a string instead of float. Floats can't exactly represent simple numbers, like for example 0.2:

```
>>> Dec(0.2)
Decimal('0.200000000000000011102230246251565404236316680908203125')
>>> Dec('0.2')
Decimal('0.2')
```

There is probably a limited number of places where you have to convert to `Decimal`. Most operations on `Decimal` either gives a new Decimal, or throws an exception.

```
>>> d = distance(x1, y1, x2, y2)
>>> d
Decimal('4.371048958774083555277441787')
>>> (d + x1*x2 + y1*y2**2) / 100
Decimal('1.542359709587740835552774418')
```

I know this is not perfect, but it might help.